# R functions that execute functions

Tags: r, r-package

I'm trying to break out common lines of code used in a fairly large R script into encapsulated functions...however, they don't seem to be running the intended code when called. I feel like I'm missing some conceptual piece of how R works, or functional programming in general.

Examples:

Here's a piece of code I'd like to call to clear the workspace -

```
clearWorkSpace <- function() {
  rm(list= ls(all=TRUE))
}
```

As noted, the code inside of the function executes as expected, however if the parent function is called, the environment is not cleared.

Again, here's a function intended to load all dependency files -

```
loadDependencies <- function() {
  dep_files <- list.files(path="./dependencies")
  for (file in dep_files) {
    file_path <- paste0("./dependencies/",file)
    source(file_path,local=TRUE)
  }
}
```

If possible, it'd be great to be able to encapsulate code into easy to read functions. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are calling *workspace* is more properly referred to as the *global environment*.

Functions execute in their own *environments*. This is, for example, why you don't see the variables defined *inside* a function in your global environment. Also how a function knows to use a variable named `x` defined in the function body rather than some `x` you might happen to have in your global environment.

Most functions don't modify the external environments, which is good! It's the functional programming paradigm. Functions that do modify environments, such as `rm` and `source`, usually take arguments so that you can be explicit about which environment is modified. If you look at `?rm` you'll see an `envir` argument, and that argument is most of what its *Details* section describes. `source` has a `local` argument:

> `local` - `TRUE`, `FALSE` or an environment, determining where the parsed expressions are evaluated. `FALSE` (the default) corresponds to the user's workspace (the global environment) and `TRUE` to the environment from which `source` is called.

You explicitly set `local = TRUE` when you call `source`, which explicitly tells `source` to only modify the local (inside the function) environment, so of course your global environment is untouched!

---

To make your functions work as I assume you want them to, you could modify `clearWorkSpace` like this:

```
clearWorkSpace <- function() {
  rm(list= ls(all=TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

And for `loadDependencies` simply delete the `local = TRUE`. (Or more explicitly set `local = FALSE` or `local = .GlobalEnv`) Though you could re-write it in a more R-like way:

```
loadDependencies = function() {
    invisible(lapply(list.files(path = "./dependencies", full.names = TRUE), source))
}
```

For both of these (especially with the simplified dependency running above) I'd question whether you really need these wrapped up in functions. Might be better to just get in the habit of restarting R when you resume work on a project and keeping `invisible(lapply(list.files(path = "./dependencies", full.names = TRUE), source))` at the top of your script...

---

For more reading on environments, there is [The Evironments Section of Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html). Notably, there are several ways to specify environments that might be useful for different use cases rather than hard-coding the global environment.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you need just to do something like:

```
 rm(list= ls(all=TRUE, envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

I mean you set explicitly the environment ( even it is better here to use `pos` argument).  but this will delete also the `clearWorkSpace` function since it is a defined in the global environment. So this will fails with a  recursive call.

Personally I never use `rm` within a function or a local call. My understanding , `rm` is **intended to be called from the console** to clear the work space.